# How can I check/compute the "delete hit rate" on redis?

Tags: redis, redis-cli

It's well known that we are able to calculate redis hit-rate by using 
`redis-cli info` command(to check key_hits and key_misses).

However, these two metrics record only hits&misses in query cases(i.e., **GET** command) . Are there any ways to solve my problem (recoding the successful rate of all executed DEL commands)?

Comment: As we all know, when deleting a key, it will return either 1 or 0, meaning success(hit) and failure(miss)  respectively. These would not affect the acquired metrics we obtain by `redis-cli info` command.

Comment: it seems you can only get the number of successful delete operations, but there's no way to get the number of missed delete operations.